# vuejs and symfony5 - link to public document

Tags: vue.js, symfony, twig, symfony5

I have a refered documents for my entity and render this in vuejs like this:

```
<span v-for="document in assignment.documents">
    <a target="_blank" href="">
        <small>{{ document.id }}.{{ document.extension }}</small>
    </a>
</span>
```

the documents are stored in public/uploads/documents/*.*

How can I generate a valid href to my documents like I can do this in twig:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{ asset('/uploads/documents/' ~ document.id ~ '.' ~ document.extension) }}">
    {{ document.name }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a binding to the `href` attribute and use both a string and a variable inside the binding, which is interpreted as a JavaScript expression:

```
<a :href="'/uploads/documents/' + document.id + '.' + document.extension">
```

`:href` is shorthand for `v-bind:href`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using ES2015 like this:

```
<a :href="`/uploads/documents/${document.id}.${document.extension}`">
```